# Fluent-NHibernate added Multiple Data To Database MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, transactions, fluent-nhibernate, addition

I have a project with fluent-nhibernate.  And here is my models and mapping:

TapuKisiKisi.cs:

```
 public class TapuKisiModel : SModuleClass
{
    public virtual int Kod { get; set; }
    public virtual long TapuKod { get; set; }
    public virtual string Ad { get; set; }
    public virtual TapuKisiTipModel KisiTip { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual IList<TapuHisseBilgisiModel> HisseBilgisi { get; set; }

    public virtual TapuTuzelKisiModel TuzelKisi { get; set; }
    public virtual TapuGercekKisiModel GercekKisi { get; set; }


    public TapuKisiModel()
    {
        HisseBilgisi = new List<TapuHisseBilgisiModel>();
    }


}
```

TapuKisiModelMap.cs:

```
 public class TapuKisiModelMap : ClassMap<TapuKisiModel>
{
    public TapuKisiModelMap()
    {
        Table("TAPU_KISI");

        Id(x => x.Kod);

        Map(x => x.Ad);
        Map(x => x.TapuKod);

        Map(x => x.Record).Length(25).Nullable();
        Map(x => x.RecordDate).Nullable();
        Map(x => x.Edit).Length(25);
        Map(x => x.EditDate);


        References(x => x.KisiTip).PropertyRef(x => x.TapuKod).Column("CinsiyetTapuKod").Index("IX_KISI_CINSIYETTAPUKOD");
        References(x => x.GercekKisi).Column("GercekKisiKod").Cascade.SaveUpdate().Index("IX_KISI_GERCEKKISIKOD");
        References(x => x.TuzelKisi).Column("TuzelKisiKod").Cascade.SaveUpdate().Index("IX_KISI_TUZELKISIKOD");
        HasMany(x => x.HisseBilgisi).PropertyRef("TapuKod").KeyColumn("KisiTapuKod").Cascade.SaveUpdate();

    }
}
```

TapuHisseBilgisiModel.cs:

```
 public partial class TapuHisseBilgisiModel : SModuleClass
{

    public virtual int Kod { get; set; }
    public virtual long TapuKod { get; set; }
    public virtual string EdinmeSebep { get; set; }
    public virtual decimal HissePay { get; set; }
    public virtual decimal HissePayda { get; set; }
    public virtual TapuIslemModel Islem { get; set; }


}
```

TapuHisseBilgisiModelMap.cs:

```
 public TapuHisseBilgisiModelMap()
    {
        Table("TAPU_HISSE_BILGISI");

        Id(x => x.Kod);

        Map(x => x.TapuKod);
        Map(x => x.EdinmeSebep);
        Map(x => x.HissePay);
        Map(x => x.HissePayda);

        Map(x => x.Record).Length(25).Nullable();
        Map(x => x.RecordDate).Nullable();
        Map(x => x.Edit).Length(25);
        Map(x => x.EditDate);

        HasOne(x => x.Islem).ForeignKey("HisseBilgisiTapuKod").PropertyRef(x => x.HisseBilgisi);
        References(x => x.Kisi).PropertyRef(x => x.TapuKod).Column("KisiTapuKod").Index("IX_HISSEBILGISI_KISITAPUKOD");
        References(x => x.Zemin).PropertyRef(x => x.TapuKod).Column("ZeminTapuKod").Index("IX_HISSEBILGISI_ZEMINTAPUKOD");

    }
```

My models and mappings are like these. When i run project working normally. But when i call again same method to save database it's adding same data again. I need only update if data is exist.

And here is my source to kisi adding database:

```
  internal bool AddKisiToDatabase(List<TapuKisiModel> kisiList)
    {
        using (ISession session = DatabaseProvider.SessionFactory.OpenSession())
        {
            using (ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
            {
                try
                {
                    foreach (var kisi in kisiList)
                    {
                        TapuKisiModel currentKisi = session
                            .QueryOver<TapuKisiModel>()
                            .Where(x => x.TapuKod == kisi.TapuKod)
                            .SingleOrDefault();
                        if (currentKisi != null)
                        {

                            currentKisi.TapuKod = kisi.TapuKod;
                            foreach (var hisse in kisi.HisseBilgisi)
                            {
                                currentKisi.HisseBilgisi.Add(hisse);
                            }
                            session.Update(currentKisi);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            session.Save(kisi);
                        }
                    }
                    transaction.Commit();
                    return true;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    SNLog.SLogger.Error(string.Format("{0} - {1}", "An Error Occurred While Adding tuzelKisiList To Database", ex.Message));
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I run this code first time adding kisi to database and adding hissebilgisi too. But i run this code second time it's update kisi data in database and adding hissebilgisi again. So there will duplicated hissebilgisi in database. I don't want that. I need if need update hissebilgisi too, if there is no hissebilgisi add to database.

What should i do?

Note:I'm sorry my english is not very well i know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should be work

```
    internal bool AddKisiToDatabase(List<TapuKisiModel> kisiList)
    {
        bool state = false;
        using (ISession session = DatabaseProvider.SessionFactory.OpenSession())
        {
            try
            {
                using (ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
                {
                    foreach (var kisi in kisiList)
                    {
                        TapuKisiModel currentKisi = new TapuKisiModel();

                        currentKisi = session
                            .QueryOver<TapuKisiModel>()
                            .Where(x => x.TapuKod == kisi.TapuKod)
                            .SingleOrDefault();

                        session.SaveOrUpdate(currentKisi);
                        transaction.Commit();
                    }
                }
                state = true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                SNLog.SLogger.Error(string.Format("{0} - {1}", "An Error Occurred While Adding tuzelKisiList To Database", ex.Message));
            }

        }
        return state;
    }
```